# How to Create Excel with Autofilter Functionality from ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, excel, observablecollection, autofilter

How to Create **Excel** with **Autofilter** Functionality from ObservableCollection in C# ?

AutoFilter for all Column Header of a MobileModel in the Model Class.

The Model and View Model are pasted below :- C# Coding

```
public class Mobile
{
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModel> _mobileList;
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModel> MobileList
    {
        get { return _mobileList; }
        set { _mobileList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public void GetMobile()
    {
        List<MobileModel> mList = new List<MobileModel>();
        List<MobileModelInfo> modList = new List<MobileModelInfo>();
        MobileModel mob = new MobileModel();

        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Apple";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "iPhone 6", Catagory = "Premium Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "IOS";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Samsung";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "MicroSoft";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Lumina 9900", Catagory = "Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "Opera X220", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Windows";
        mList.Add(mob);

        mob = new MobileModel();
        modList.Clear();
        mob.Brand = "Sony Ericssion";
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S4", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2011" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S5", Catagory = "Smart Phone", Year = "2013" });
        modList.Add(new MobileModelInfo { Name = "S6", Catagory = "Ultra Smart Phone", Year = "2015" });
        mob.Model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>(modList);
        mob.OS = "Android";
        mList.Add(mob);

        MobileList = new ObservableCollection<MobileModel>(mList);

        ExportToExcel(MobileList);

    }


    public void ExportToExcel(ObservableCollection<MobileModel> Source)
    {
        // How to Create Excel Sheet with AutoFilter from ObservableCollection<MobileModel>
    }

}

public class MobileModel : Notify
{
    private string _brand = string.Empty;
    private ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> _model = new ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo>();
    private string _os = string.Empty;

    public string Brand
    {
        get { return _brand; }
        set { _brand = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MobileModelInfo> Model
    {
        get { return _model; }
        set { _model = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string OS
    {
        get { return _os; }
        set { _os = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}

public class MobileModelInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add Reference "**Microsoft Office Interop Excel**"
[Snapshot of Adding Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUdrV.jpg)

Step 2: Include the "**Microsoft Office Interop Excel**" in your class file

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Win32;
```

Step 3: ExportToExcel() Method

```
    public void ExportToExcel(ObservableCollection<MobileModel> MobileList)
    {
        if (MobileList.Count > 0)
        {
            // Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Image
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File|*.xls";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File";
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Mobile List";

            // If the User Clicks the Save Button then the Module gets executed otherwise it skips the scope
            if ((bool)saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog())
            {

                Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                if (xlApp != null)
                {
                    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "";

                    Excel.Range formatRange;

                    int rowCount = 1;

                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 1] = "Brand";
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = "OS";

                    rowCount++;

                    formatRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("a1"); formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
                    formatRange = xlWorkSheet.Range["a1"]; formatRange.Cells.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    formatRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("b1"); formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

                    foreach (var item in MobileList)
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 1] = item.Brand;
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount, 2] = item.OS;

                        rowCount++;
                    }

                    formatRange = xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1], xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, rowCount - 1]]; formatRange.AutoFilter(1, Type.Missing, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);

                    xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();

                    // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()))
                    {
                        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                        xlApp.Quit();

                        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                        releaseObject(xlApp);

                        MessageBox.Show("Excel File Exported Successfully", "Export Engine");
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to Export", "Export Engine");
        }
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            System.GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```